# Deutsches Äquivalent zu: »That’s the way the cookie crumbles.«

Tags: phrase-request, proverb

> That’s the way the cookie crumbles.

[Gebrauch](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/that-s-the-way-the-cookie-crumbles):
*said when something slightly unlucky has happened that could not have been prevented and so must be accepted.*

Gibt es ein Äquivalent auf Deutsch? „So ist das Leben“ fällt mir ein, aber vielleicht gibt es was besseres.

Comment: *So isch's halt em Schwarzwald, wenn dr Furz knallt, dann schtenkts halt.*

Comment: Möglicherweise relevant: [German alternatives to "shit happens"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3277)

Comment: You can try to break a cookie into four equal pieces, but cracks are jagged and somewhat random, determined by unseen factors that are impossible to control. Often life is similar and the result is that one can be the victim unfair or unfortunate random events. So I think the expression is meant to compare the two, and this accounts for variations such as "It depends on how the cookie crumbles." On the other hand, it's possible that it's referencing fortune cookies, with the fortune representing the random outcome. Just speculation, but I hope it helps define the meaning.

Answer (score 7):

> So läuft der Hase!

oder auch

> Das ist nunmal wie der Hase läuft.

(Er schlägt Haken, was die Verfolgung erschwert.)

Die Phrase wird oft verwendet, um eingebürgerte Verfahrensweisen, die einen Neuling vielleicht überraschen, als Usus zu kommentieren.

Comment: Möchte behaupten hinter "Hase" verbirgt sich Franz. *chose* "Sache".

Answer (score 4):

> Das Leben ist kein Ponyhof

und

> Das Leben ist kein Wunschkonzert

könnten eventuell auch passen. Beide betonen, dass es Dinge gibt, auf die man keinen Einfluss hat.

Answer (score 3):

Mir fällt leider nichts ein, das so humorvoll ist wie "that's the way the cookie crumbles".

Ein paar eher humorfreie Arten, dasselbe zu sagen:

Basic:

> (Das) kann man (jetzt) (halt) nicht ändern.

Einer der wenigen französischen Sätze, die im Deutschen benutzt werden:

> C'est la vie!

Beliebt sind bei dem Thema auch Dialekt-Sprüche wie:

> Et kütt wie et kütt. (Rheinisch, "Es kommt, wie es kommt.")
> (Jetz) isch's halt so. (Schwäbisch, "So ist es halt nun mal.")

Ich weiß nicht, wie das folgende eigentlich mal wörtlich gemeint war, aber es bedeutet (sehr umgangssprachlich) im Norddeutschen etwa das gleiche wie "Man kann es sich nicht aussuchen." oder "Man kann nicht vorhersehen, wie es ausgeht.":

> Man steckt (halt) nicht drin. / Da steckst du nicht drin.

Comment: Im Norddeutschen auch gern "Joa (ne), is halt so, wie's is"

Comment: Ich denke man kann die Kernaussagen vom zerbrechenden Keks in "halt" zusammenfassen. Das ist so vs Das ist halt so. Letzteres sagt eben aus, dass da nichts zu machen ist. Ich denke das kann man in der Antwort nochmal klar betonen, herausstellen.

Comment: ich glaube eher, die Bunte Mischung an Antworten kan man mit dem *weiß ich nicht Digga* Meme zusammenfassen, um dies auf das vorherschende Verständnis von der Bedeutung zu beziehen.

Answer (score 1):

> Wo gehobelt wird, fallen Späne

comes to mind.

Comment: This refers to unfortunate but unavoidable consequences of actions (especially as a side effect), and can *not* be used for things that just happen.

Answer (score 1):

> Das ist der Lauf der Dinge

oder

> So ist der Lauf der Dinge

sind übliche deutsche Varianten.

Answer (score -2):

> So zerbröselt der Keks nunmal

That's a literal translation used in the German dub of Trumanshow (with Jim Carry). The original implication was that the phrase, "and that's how the cookie crumbles", is inappropriate when referring to an actual, oversized cookie.

So it seems that no idiomatic translation conveys a similar connotation. The literal one is passable only because it was intended to sound idiosyncratic.

Besides, an idiom to capture actual usage must exist: *said when something slightly unlucky has happened that could not have been prevented and so must be accepted.*

- “Ja so ist das mit dem Licht, manchmal brennt es, manchmal nicht”, may be shortened to the first clause, connotated with different meanings of “Licht” or used out of context
- “Scheiße passiert” (shit happens, literally). More specifically, “Scheiße fällt nach unten”, i.e. those at the bottom suffer the most.
- “jeder will ein Stück vom Kuchen” (a piece of the pie, vis-a-vis cookie)
- “der Zahn der Zeit” (tooth of time, since Shakespear and earlier), e.g.: “dass der Zahn der Zeit auch vor Zelluloid nicht halt macht”. ~ *nagt*: “der Zahn der Zeit nagt auch an ihnen”

*Cookie* is originally from Dutch *koekje* ‘kleine koeken als versnapering’. Nicoline van der Sijs (2009, Yankees, Cookies and Dollars) elaborates:

> “Ongeveer een eeuw later ontstond **(that’s) how (of the way) the cookie crumbles**, ‘zo gaat dat nu eenmaal, zo lopen de zaken’

(https://etymologiebank.nl/trefwoord/koekje)

Dutch is so close to Germam, the glosses translate almost one-to-one without loss of fidelity:

> *so geht das nun einmal*

> *so läuft das [hier, bei uns, dort, ...]*

Although “lopende zaken” appears to be a more Dutch idiom referring to business, that isn't easily translated (cp. *ein Ding zu laufen haben*, Engl. *to think you are the big cheese*?).

At any rate it shows that Dutch too has no corresponding idiom, so it's a New York new thing. The real meaning is less than clear.

Comment: Wenn eine Frage auf Deutsch gestellt ist, sollte man auch auf Deutsch antworten.

Comment: Naja, die Übersetzungen sind ja auch auf Deutsch. Diese den deutsch Sprechenden zu erklären, wäre irgendwie sinnfrei, zumal die Frage zur hälfte englisch ist und sich da auch keine Mühe gemacht hat, das anzupassen.